# How to get date in following format "2017-06-06T07:00:00.000Z" in Python?

Tags: python, date, time

I would like to get current date/time in the following format "2017-06-06T07:00:00.000Z" in Python. I have JSON that contains this date formatting and I would like to imitate this. Any idea if this a standard (ISO) format or how I can get this format? I couldn't find this format on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is ISO format (see [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)) and you can produce it in Python in several ways, in particular using `time.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ", time.gmtime())`.